# What's a CD socket in a motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, compact-disc, sockets

In my motherboard I have a socket which says "CD".

It looks like a 4 pin fan socket, more or less.

Is it a fan socket, or what is it used for?

I have tried googleing it but I only find results about Compact Discs.

My motherboard is an [Asus M2N MX SE](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M2NMX_SE/)

[image]

Comment: According to http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090211015116AAf8Wyd, "*The 4-pin audio connector is a legacy device and isn't really needed anymore nowadays. Also, it plugs into your sound card, not the case.*". But I don't trust Yahoo Answers, can someone confirm that and explain it a bit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optical drive audio in connector (4-pin CD)
These connectors allow you to receive stereo audio input from sound source such as CD-Rom, TV tuner or MPEG card

that is according to page 1-28 of the manual for your motherboard that I downloaded from the link you gave.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I didn't see there was a manual, I'm gonna read it.

Answer (score 3):

In ye early days CDROMs were not only capable of reading data CDs, but also of playing audio CDs. To listen to the music from an audio CD you either plugged in a headphone on the connecor on the front of the CDROM, or you connected the drives audio out to your soundcards.

In your case this 'soundcard' is in the motherboard.

Example image oif an old CDROM (The orange part at the bottom is where you would connect the cable leading to the sound card, or in your case to the motherboard).

[image]

Comment: You could, if you were crazy enough, play music off a CD player with an appropriate powersupply, and the right leads, with no computer I suspect.